# Случайное действие при определенном условии

Tags: php

Подскажите куда смотреть. Есть `$x`. Как сделать так, что бы при определенном значении `$x` выполнялось случайное действие.

```
if ($x == "some") {
 echo $a, $b;
// или
 echo $c, $d;
// или
 echo $e, $f;
}
```

Comment: Используйте оператор `switch...case` или `if...elseif`. Первый в вашем случае предпочтительнее. [Читайте доки](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.switch.php)

Answer (score 1):

Действия могут вызываться случайно, но вероятно сами они не бессмысленные, поэтому не помешает дать им имена.

```
// имена действий (только для наглядности)
$actions = ['alfa', 'beta', 'chi', 'delta', 'epsilon'];

// При определенном значении $x
if ($x == "some") {
  // случайное действие
  $i = mt_rand(0, count($actions) - 1); // индекс в известных пределах 
  echo "Call {$actions[$i]}\n"; // 
  switch ($actions[$i]) {
    case 'alfa': echo $a, $b; break;
    case 'beta': echo $c, $d; break;
    // ...
    default: echo 'неописанное действие!';
  }
}
```

**P.S.** Кстати, вместо перечисления имен в массиве можно использовать имена всех методов определенного объекта.

```
// ...
$actions = get_class_methods($o);
$i = mt_rand(0, count($actions) - 1);
echo "Call {$actions[$i]}\n";
$o->{$actions[$i]}();
```

Comment: то, что у вас постскриптум мне не ясно, можно как то подробнее, пожалуйста. Спасибо)

Comment: Нельзя. IMHO, код самоочевиден. Если нет, то мне очень жаль.

Comment: хорошо, разберусь)

Answer (score 0):

Для случайного, надо использовать генератор случайного :-)

```
if ($x == "some") {
 $choise = rand(1,4);
 if($choise==1)
   echo $a, $b;
 else if($choise==2)
// или
 else if($choise==3)
   echo $c, $d;
 else
// или
   echo $e, $f;
}
```